# Return full domain object from Grails / GORM projection

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I would like to get a list containing the most recent book written by each of a list of given authors. I tried this:

```
List books = Book.withCriteria {
  inList('author', authors)
  projections {
    groupProperty('author')
    max('releaseDate')
  }
}
```

This seems to work but unfortunately instead of a List of Books, this returns a List of Lists, each inner list being like [author, releaseDate].

How can I get it to return a list of the relevant books?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use HQL for this and use a subquery, something like:

```
Book.executeQuery("""
     from Book as book 
     where book.id in (
         select id from Book b group by b.author order by b.releaseDate desc
     )
""")
```